# How To Uniquely Identify An Android Device?

Tags: android

I was working on an app (server-android client) that allow user to sign in from multiple android devices. When user logged in on a device, that device will be registered on server side, but I don't know how to avoid duplicate, so I was wondering that are there any chances to uniquely identify an android device? I think Google Play and Facebook can do that.

Answer (score 8):

There are several options available, but there is no 100% guarantee that they will always work. See the android developer blog post: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Best method mentioned is [Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55977643/3906926

Answer (score 2):

You can check the `IMEI` or `MAC` address of the device.

for `IMEI`

[TelephonyManager.getDeviceId](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId) will work

for MAC

[WifiInfo.getMacAddress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getMacAddress) will work

Comment: yes but how to get the wifi address through adb shell?

Comment: @StinePike I was using the imei. If users use this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.parallel.intl&referrer=af_tranid%3DPRiStLWOu5urVvBj5RutIA%26pid%3DPSwebsite then we will get wrong imei.

Comment: Just a note taken from Android official site: `It is generally not recommended to use MAC address for any form of user identification. As a result, as of Android M, local device MAC addresses (for example, Wifi and Bluetooth) are not available via third party APIs. The WifiInfo.getMacAddress() method and the BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getAddress() method will both return 02:00:00:00:00:00`.

Comment: MAC Address can be fetched through NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() or DevicePolicyManager.

Comment: Those no longer work in Android Q :(